# lineSegment shaderMaterial - bufferGeometry (Threejs)

Tags: graph, three.js, line, shader, buffer-geometry

I'm trying to write a graph visualization with Three.js so I have a bufferGeometry to save my vertexes and I'm drawing it with my own ShaderMaterial to make thousands of Three.Points but now I want to know how shader of Three.lineSegments work to change it for my self.
I want to draw my edges with the same bufferGeometry and use two index for heads of the edge.
I had searching too much but I have not found anything?
is it possible?

Comment: Are you looking for [`THREE.Line`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/objects/Line) instead of `THREE.LineSegments`? `THREE.Line` will do what you want because it renders the vertices as a line strip.

Comment: Yes I saw but I don't want linestrip I need something can draw line with two vertex index

Comment: Then you can't use the same `BufferGeometry` object. The two shapes are of different primitive types. ([Line Primitives](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Primitive#Line_primitives), [Point Primitives](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Primitive#Point_primitives)) `GL_POINTS` obviously draws using a single vertex. `THREE.LineSegments` == `GL_LINES`, which requires two vertices per segment.  Provide indexing to allow the line segments to be continuous means the indices for the points will be wrong. It may seem like it draws correctly, but it's not. Adding draw groups exposes the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had found my answer.
We should using setindex in buffer Geometry and using same attribute of position in two bufferGeometry